# Download Statuse is Pending in download Manager

Tags: android-download-manager

I'm using Download Manager to download mp3 file in my android app.
it works on all devices, but there is just one device that the download couldn't start and the Download Status is Pending.
I checked the Internet Connection of my device and it was OK.

Comment: might be related to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026503/5400206

Comment: after I restart the device, my problem was solved.but i'll try your suggestion too,thanks.